# using autocomplete css in HTML code (no design applied for my example)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use an autocomplete's CSS in HTML code ... but it doesn't work. I tried to fetch the code from firefox, but I got no design on the HTML code.

**Let's clarify the question:**

***My need: (I want to get the same design as the image below)***
[An image about what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2drO.png)

***CSS code of this image:***
https://github.com/hailwood/jQuery-Tagit/tree/master/css/themeroller

`Tags.css` and `bootstrap/bootstrap.css`

**What I tried:**

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete">
<ul class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content">

<li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default tagit-new">
        <a href="#" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div class="ui-widget-header">
                Title <span style="font-weight:normal">(used 4 times)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-widget-content">a description here
            </div>
            </a>
</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

But no design applied for my code! I used the right `classes` and `ids`.
Please let me know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Are you just wanting to get the styles for the boxes in your image?

For starters, all of your classes are part of jQuery UI... are you using that anywhere? Those classes (`ui-autocomplete`, `ui-widget-content` etc) are not part of the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Yes i want get the style of the boxes ... yes i am using JQuery UI.

Comment: Download jQuery, and then look at the jquery-ui.theme.css file - they're all in there.

Comment: they are even in bootstrap.css of the github !

Comment: What does it look like right now if the image is your desired style?

Comment: right now i have no design on  the page, only list of html links ... nothing else.

Comment: @BetterFly how can they possibly be in the Bootstrap file..? It's nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: @Lee the bootstrap file in this github project was modified, please check it.

Comment: Well that's just asking for loads of problems then. But anyway, you're looking for the theme file I mentioned earlier

Comment: I tried it (jquery-ui.css) but i had the same result :)

Comment: I think i have made a mistake at the html code but i can't figure it out.